# How to get line number using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm using scanner to read a text file line by line but then how to get line number since scanner iterates through each input?My program is something like this:

```
s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));

while (s.hasNext()) {
System.out.print(s.next());
```

This works fine but for example:

```
1,2,3 
3,4,5
```

I want to know line number of it which mean 1,2,3 is in line 1 and 3,4,5 is in line 2.How do I get that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a [`LineNumberReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) in place of the `BufferedReader` to keep track of the line number while the scanner does its thing.

```
LineNumberReader r = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
String l;

while ((l = r.readLine()) != null) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(l);

    while (s.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Line " + r.getLineNumber() + ": " + s.next());
    }
}
```

**Note:** The "obvious" solution I first posted does not work as the scanner reads ahead of the current token.

```
r = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
s = new Scanner(r);

while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Line " + r.getLineNumber() + ": " + s.next());
}
```

Comment: It's a pity there is still no better solution than creating one Scanner per line, though. I stumbled upon the same problem as your first "naive" solution, the Scanner reads too much ahead and there doesn't seem to be any way to set a smaller buffer.

Answer (score 10):

Just put a counter in the loop:

```
s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));

for (int lineNum=1; s.hasNext(); lineNum++) {
   System.out.print("Line number " + lineNum + ": " + s.next());
}
```

Comment: I think this only works if you have .useDelimiter() set to newline. If you scan for whitespace (e.g. words) than it will count words instead.

Comment: I updated the example to use hasNextLine/nextLine so that it solves the OP's question.