# Buffered Reader readLine() with Empty lines

Tags: java, text, file, buffered

I am using buffered reader to grab a line at a time from a text file. I am trying to also get the line number from the text file using a tracking integer. Unfortunately *BufferedReader* is skipping empty lines (ones with just **/n** or the carriage return).

Is there a better way to solve this? Would using scanner work?

Example code:

```
int lineNumber = 0;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    this.charSequence.add(s, ++lineNumber);
}
```

Comment: what is your declaration of your variable s?

Comment: In future "it doesn't work" questions an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) flavored code snippet would help a lot.

Answer (score 22):

I could not reproduce your claim that `BufferedReader` skips empty lines; it should NOT have.

Here are snippets to show that empty lines aren't just skipped.

#### [`java.io.BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

```
    String text = "line1\n\n\nline4";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(text));
    String line;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.printf("%04d: %s%n", ++lineNumber, line);
    }
```

#### [`java.io.LineNumberReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html)

```
    String text = "line1\n\n\nline4";
    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(text));
    String line;
    while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.printf("%04d: %s%n", lnr.getLineNumber(), line);
    }
```

#### [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
    String text = "line1\n\n\nline4";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.printf("%04d: %s%n", ++lineNumber, sc.nextLine());
    }
```

The output for any of the above snippets is:

```
0001: line1
0002: 
0003: 
0004: line4
```

#### Related questions

- [How to get line number using scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332297/how-to-get-line-number-using-scanner) - a `LineNumberReader` + `Scanner` combo!
- [How to read a string line per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096621/how-to-read-a-string-line-per-line)
- [In Java, how to read from a file a specific line, given the line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/in-java-how-to-read-from-a-file-a-specific-line-given-the-line-number)
- [Read a specific line from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138390/read-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file)
- [Validating input using `java.util.Scanner`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner/) - has many examples
- [what do these symbolic strings mean: `%02d %01d` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377688/what-do-these-symbolic-strings-mean-02d-01d/3377719#3377719)

Comment: Doh, my bad. Found the problem code. Thanks guys, sorry for the poor question, should have looked into it more. Was stumped at that point.

Comment: Looks like I was trying to add the lines to a list but it wasn't keeping the returns.

  String s = null;
  
  this.charSequence = new LinkedList<String>(); 
  while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
  {
   this.charSequence.add(s);
  }

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at LineNumberReader?  Not sure if that will help you.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html

Comment: That is true. According to documentation readLine() behaviour for LineNumberReader is the following "Read a line of text. Whenever a line terminator is read the current line number is incremented."

Answer (score 3):

It must be the FileReader class that skips newline characters then.
I checked the results of `readLine()` again and it didn't include the new line symbol so it is happening between the two classes *FileReader* and *BufferedReader*.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String s = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        this.charSequence.add(s);
    }
} catch (...) {

}
```

Comment: Java's API says: readLine

public String readLine()
                throws IOException
Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
Returns:
A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached
Throws:
IOException - If an I/O error occurs