# java: how to use bufferedreader to read specific line

Tags: java, bufferedreader, file-handling, file-read

Lets say I have a text file called: data.txt (contains 2000 lines)

How do I read given specific line from: 500-1500 and then 1500-2000
and display the output of specific line?

this code will read whole files (2000 line)

```
public static String getContents(File aFile) {

        StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();

        try {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
        try {
            String line = null; 

            while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
            contents.append(line);
            contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        }
        finally {
            input.close();
        }
        }
            catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return contents.toString();
}
```

How do I modify above code to read specific line?

Comment: why don't you just count which line you are and if you are in the wanted range you output the lines one after one ?

Comment: how do i do that? i know how to count but not sure about output the line with the range

Comment: You count and then you check the count with an `if` statement.

Comment: you are probably need with absolute file access, try of SeekableStream

Comment: You should count lines from the beginning of the file or even better parse using `LineNumberReader`

Comment: any example would be great

Comment: LineNumberReader combined with Scanner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332297/how-to-get-line-number-using-scanner?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest java.io.LineNumberReader. It extends BufferedReader and
you can use its `LineNumberReader.getLineNumber();` to get the current line number

You can also use Java 7 `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines` which returns a `List<String>` if it suits you better

Note:

1) favour StringBuilder over StringBuffer, StringBuffer is just a legacy class

2) `contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))` does not look nice 
   use `contents.append(File.separator)` instead

3) Catching exception seems irrelevant, I would also suggest to change your code as

```
public static String getContents(File aFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aFile"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // read your lines
        return sb.toString();
    } finally {
        rdr.close();
    }
}
```

now code looks cleaner in my view.  And if you are in Java 7 use try-with-resources

```
    try (BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aFile"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // read your lines
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

so finally your code could look like

```
public static String[] getContents(File aFile) throws IOException {
    try (LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(aFile))) {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = null; (line = rdr.readLine()) != null;) {
            if (rdr.getLineNumber() >= 1500) {
                sb2.append(line).append(File.pathSeparatorChar);
            } else if (rdr.getLineNumber() > 500) {
                sb1.append(line).append(File.pathSeparatorChar);
            }
        }
        return new String[] { sb1.toString(), sb2.toString() };
    }
}
```

Note that it returns 2 strings 500-1499 and 1500-2000

Comment: It seems Redbox wants 500-1500 and 1500 - 2000 as two separate texts, or so it seems

Comment: i want to put the text of (500-1500) to stringA
then text of (1500-2000) as stringB
possible to do that?

Comment: Then use LineNumberReader, it will be more efficent

Comment: 1 more question, StringBuilder is for jdk 1.4 and above?

Comment: do you have other way than stringbuilder? as my project is using older version of jdk, the stringbuilder is not working..

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more cleaner solution would be to use FileUtils in apache commons.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html
Example snippet:

```
String line = FileUtils.readLines(aFile).get(lineNumber);
```

Comment: do i need to load apache libs? im using jdeveloper

Comment: Yes, apache commons-io jar file should be in the classpath. http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Comment: the link in your answer is dead
You find FileUtils in here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Answer (score 4):

The better way is to use BufferedReader. If you want to read line 32 for example:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++){
    buf.readLine();
}
lineThreeTwo = buf.readLine();
```

Now in String lineThreeTwo you have stored line 32.

Comment: BufferedReader is faster than LineNumberReader. Fastest solution.