# get Data from text file in java

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I have text file `a.txt` and I want to a methode like  `public String[] getdata(String filename,int nbrLine){}` that I give two parameters the name of the file (`a.txt`) and the number of the line  that I want to put in `String[]`.

I have text file `a.txt`

```
1,2,3,5,0
7,2,3,5,4,7
9,2
1,0,0,2`
```

I try something like

```
public String LoadDataB(String inFile) {
     String tContents = "";
     try {
         InputStream stream = getAssets().open(inFile);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.available()];
         stream.read(buffer);
         stream.close();
         return new String(buffer);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return tContents;
     }
 }
```

But how can I complete it?

Comment: but i want to get a specific line

Comment: if you want only one line why do you ask for `String[] getdata(String filename,int nbrLine)` which returns string **array**?

Comment: I think the first answer there can help you. It says "Then, you can use in.readLine(); to read a single line at a time."

Comment: for example in my txt fil a have

Comment: look at the linked question. if you want a specific line skip the rest.

Comment: if i give the nbrline is 3 i want String array content [1,0,0,2] .

Comment: but where i should put the number of the line that i want

Comment: you maintain a line counter, you ++ it every line you read, when you get to the one you want (counter == arg) you return it.

Comment: can you give me a example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217997/java-how-to-use-bufferedreader-to-read-specific-line

Comment: i try it but doesnt work