# How do I read from a certain line until a certain line?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, readline, printwriter

For example I want to read a text file from line number 20056 until line 1159450 and outputs it into the output window but I do not know how to do so as the method `line.readline()` starts with the first line.

This is my code:

```
String line;
int currentLineNo = 1;
int startLine = 20056;//40930;
int endLine = 1159450;

FileReader file = new FileReader("yourfilepath");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("yourfilepath", "UTF-8");

while (currentLineNo < startLine) {
    currentLineNo++;
}

while(currentLineNo >= startLine && currentLineNo <= endLine) {
    // System.out.println(currentLineNo);
    line = reader.readLine();

    System.out.println(line);
    // writer.println(line);
    currentLineNo++;
}

reader.close();
writer.close();
```

How do I print only from line 20056 until line 1159450 and outputs it into the output window?

Comment: In your first `while` loop, you're not advancing your `reader`. If you call `reader.readLine()` inside the loop, it will use up a line each iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a specific line using the specific line number from a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/how-to-read-a-specific-line-using-the-specific-line-number-from-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217997/java-how-to-use-bufferedreader-to-read-specific-line

Comment: how do i associate the readLine with the currentLineNo @khelwood ?

Comment: How do I not read the first few lines I do not want ? @khelwood

Comment: Yes I have been referring to many question but none of it works T_T @JayHamilton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP).*

I just need to remove the first while loop.

```
String line;
    int currentLineNo = 1;
    int startLine = 20056;//40930;
    int endLine = 1159450;

    FileReader file = new FileReader("yourfilepath");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("yourfilepath", "UTF-8");

    while(currentLineNo<=endLine) 
    {
        line = reader.readLine();
        if(currentLineNo >= startLine && currentLineNo<=endLine) 
        {  System.out.println(line); }

        currentLineNo++;
    }

    reader.close();
    writer.close();
```

Credit to Jay Hamilton.

Answer (score 1):

```
String line;
int currentLineNo = 1;
int startLine = 20056;//40930;
int endLine = 1159450;

FileReader file = new FileReader("yourfilepath");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("yourfilepath", "UTF-8");

while (currentLineNo <= endLine)
{
    line = reader.readLine();
    if(currentLineNo >= startLine && currentLineNo<=endLine) 
    {  System.out.println(line); }

    currentLineNo++;
}

reader.close();
writer.close();
```

Comment: It still prints the first line :/ I need it to print only from line 20056 until line 1159450

Comment: try jays code with your first while loop commented out.

Comment: It worked ! I just need to delete the first while loop thank you very much jay ! Have a nice day :D

Comment: Worked. Thank you spanglerb :D

Comment: Thank Jay he did the heavy lifting :-) I hear accepting answers is a good thank you present.

Comment: Edited the question with the answer and credited to Jay :)

Comment: I did but it says vote less than 15 are recorded but will not be displayed Jay :/

Comment: @NikMohamadLokman: you are probably trying to upvote. Instead, click on the tick mark to the left, so that it turns green. This is what we mean by "accepting an answer". Thanks.