# Using lines in .txt files as data in testing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For the framework our team is building, we are required to make a text file that we will edit before we run tests. That text file has two lines - the URL of our web application, and the location of an excel file that contains test cases.

Right now, for reading the file, I've been using `Scanner`.

```
 private static void readFile(String fileName) {
   try {
     File file = new File(fileName);
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
       System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
     }
     scanner.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

My code lingo isn't the best so try to get what I'm asking:

Could someone point me in the right direction of extracting these two lines (the URL and the Excel path) from the text file, assigning them to two different variables/objects/functions/whatever you really want to call them, and than passing them into the main test script, so the test script knows what it wants to do.

I drew a picture in paint. Took 100 hours.

[image: 100 hours in paint]

Comment: What's the format of the file? As is, your code should be able to read them just fine as long as each path is on its own line.

Comment: how about the Properties object ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Comment: The format is a .txt. It's a little notepad. It reads it fine, I'm just wondering how to get it to read it than pass it into my script. @svarog Haven't ever used Properties. I'll read that right now and let you know.

Comment: Try using Reader Objects https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html and assign by String str1 = reader.readLine()

Comment: Declare an int variable and just +1 for each line. Then you can do an 'if int == 0 (url = scanner.nextLine()). However, if you do this, it won't allow you to add lines to that text file. You'll have to explicitly declare what each line of that txt file is.

Comment: @RyanCarlisle But if my .txt file will always only have two lines, that shouldn't be a problem right? I could assign line 0 to a URL variable and line 1 to the Excel path variable and than pass them?

Comment: Correct, if you don't change that text file layout, you will be fine. See below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String urlText;
private String excelLocation;

private static void readFile(String fileName) {
   try {
     int lineNumber = 0;
     File file = new File(fileName);
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
       lineNumber++;
       if (lineNumber == 1){
       urlText = scanner.nextLine();
       }
       else{
       excelLocation = scanner.nextLine();
     }
     scanner.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

If you wanted to be more verbose, you can also use a LineNumberReader. See here: [How to get line number using scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332297/how-to-get-line-number-using-scanner)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) Object

to write to a file:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
OutputStream output = null;

try {

    output = new FileOutputStream("yourfile.txt");

    // set the properties value
    prop.setProperty("database", "localhost");
    prop.setProperty("dbuser", "john");
    prop.setProperty("dbpassword", "password");

    // save properties to project root folder
    prop.store(output, null);

} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (output != null) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

to read:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {

    input = new FileInputStream("yourfile.txt");

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    // get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and you will get a "yourfile.txt" file with these lines:

```
dbpassword=password
database=localhost
dbuser=john
```

I've taken the code from: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/